# Getting the value of an Advanced Custom Fields box on a taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have been tasked with creating a custom taxonomy ('sector') for a custom post type ('case_study'), on a WordPress site that already uses ACF.

Everywhere online tells me that to get the field (an image specifically, called 'sector_image'), to use get_field, and to get it for a custom taxonomy, use the tax name before the Term ID in the second parameter, like so:

```
$image = get_field('sector_image', 'sector-'.$sector->term_id);
```

I can confirm that `$sector->term_id` returns the term ID of the current term (looping through a get_terms object), but I don't get anything returned, even when I print the $image var.

edit: damn, figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well as per usual I figured it out just as I posted it, it turns out, unlike many places I saw listed, the second parameter of `get_field` requires the taxonomy slug and the term ID to be seperated by an *underscore*, **not** a hyphen or no seperator at all as listed by lots of answers online, not sure if the usage has changed at some point in the past, but yes, this works:

```
$image = get_field('sector_image', 'sector_'.$sector->term_id);
```